# Rickshaw js realtime current time stamp

Tags: time, diagram, rickshaw, stamp

I'm using the javascript rickshaw library to visualize realtime data in a diagram. Does anyone know why a time stamp of the x-Axis starts at "01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" instead of the current time stamp?

Here the x-Axis time stamp is the current time which I'd like to use:
http://jsfiddle.net/n68teee2/

Here in my project the time stamp is set to the wrong unix time stamp above:
http://jsfiddle.net/t2cch5rw/1/

I think the affected code could be the following lines:

```
var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail( {
    graph: graph
} );

var annotator = new Rickshaw.Graph.Annotate( {
    graph: graph,
    element: document.getElementById('timeline')
} );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the origin of the problem. The function Rickshaw.Fixtures.RandomData(150) adds timestamps to the data. The time stamp is defined in Rickshaw.Fixtures.Time.